# Use generated Dialog data from LUIS in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have registered a application in `LUIS`, created my intents/entities, and trained my application to identify departure/arrival and date.

This works fine when I'm testing it out. On my intent I have also added parameters and dialog prompts.

[image]

For example when using the search term `Book a flight to Boston` i get the following Json data from LUIS:

```
"dialog": {
    "prompt": "From where?",
    "parameterName": "Departure",
    "parameterType": "Location::FromLocation",
    "contextId": "75747794-f724-4b93-9406-6231237a3d78",
    "status": "Question"
}
```

In my Bot I have the following `LuisIntent`:

```
    [LuisIntent("BookFlight")]
    public async Task BookFlight(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        EntityRecommendation fromLocation;
        EntityRecommendation toLocation;
        EntityRecommendation travelDate;

        if (result.TryFindEntity("Location::FromLocation", out fromLocation) && result.TryFindEntity("Location::ToLocation", out toLocation) && result.TryFindEntity("builtin.datetime.date", out travelDate))
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"You want to travel from {fromLocation.Entity} to {toLocation.Entity} {travelDate.Entity}");
        }
        else
        {
            //Add code to retrieve the weather
            await context.PostAsync($"Could not parse your request");
        }

        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
```

This works fine, but I realize I don't use the generated dialog data that `LUIS` provide me. How can I dynamically generate dialogs based on the dialog data Luis returns?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely. But cannot wrap my head around the concept. Trying to use `LuisActionDialog` and cannot find how to populate the parameters `luisservice' and `contextId`. And how do I act on when getting a finished status in the dialog data back from LUIS?

Comment: You don't need to anything; it happens automatically. Make sure you have the latest version of BotBuilder. Once you send LUIS a utterance with missing parameters, the BotBuilder code will detect that and will automatically launch the LuisActionDialog asking for those missing parameters

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.